# Dell PERC Patrol Read makes machine unusable

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, dell-perc

I have three Dell Poweredge 2950's. One with RAID-5 on 5 disks and two with RAID-5 on 3 disks. The latter two started to have performance issues - very high IO delay. When I checked the RAID status I found out that they are doing a patrol read on one disk. Also there are no SMART errors or anything similar - the disks seem to be fine, but I only used them for one week, so I can't be sure about that.

Patrol Reads should not reduce IO performances too much, right? But I can't use those machines anymore. I rebooted one of them and it won't boot correctly because it can't finish some of the start jobs and it takes like 30 minutes until I get a shell. Also the patrol read started about 20 hours ago, so it should be done by now.

I don't have OMSA installed, so I can't do anything about it and I can't install it because the IO delay is too damn high.

So my questions are:

- Why does the Patrol Read render my systems unusable - but only two of my three machines?
- Why does the Patrol Read take so long? I know that it restarts when the system reboots. I only rebooted one machine, so the other one should have finished in time.
- How do I fix this? I guess I have to somehow stop the Patrol Read in order to do anything useful - like installing management software.

EDIT: The hard drives are Dell WD7502ABYS - so they are enterprise class disks.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite strange: patrol read should only work when disks are idle.

I strongly suspect something other is at play here. Are you using desktop-grade disks? Maybe one or more disks have read problems and the read load cause firmware-dependant timeouts (ie when using disks without TLER or similar).

Can you post controller and disks specification and details?

Comment: Agreed. Best chance to stop the problems might be setting patrol read settings to "manual" instead of automatic. This should only be a short-term work-around though, as patrol reads are arguably crucial when using an already dangerous RAID type.